# NodeJS nexe fusebox fail

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert a nodejs app in .exe.
For this i tried with pkg, but it gives error for half node-modules.
So i'm trying with next.
But when i execute the

```
nexe index.js
```

if gives this error:

```
nexe 2.0.0-rc.34

FuseBox failed to initialize. Please check that:
  - the TypeScript version installed is >= 3.0
```

So i verified with `npm list typescript -g` that the version of typescript installed in nexe is the 2.5.3.
Instead the fuse-box `npm list fuse-box -g` is the 3.7.0.

I also tried, in my package.json of the app, to add at the end:

```
"resolutions": {
  "nexe/fuse-box": "3.1.0"
}
```

Then i also tried to reinstall nexe with:

```
npm i nexe@next -g
```

But nothing, it continue to gives that error.
How can i solve? Thank you? Or there is an other library instead nexe to use to convert for a single executable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried

`npm uninstall -g nexe`

`npm i -g nexe@next`

which works on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved using this command

```
npx nexe@next --build
```

to build a node version from source!

And worked perfectly!